# Whats wrong with my function converting bin to dec using Horner?

Tags: c++

```
int bintodec(string s)
{
    int W=(s[s.size()-1] - 48);
    int x=2;
    for(int i=s.size()-2; i>=0; i--)
    {
        W=W*x+(s[i] - 48);
    }
    return W;
}
```

For example for "1011" it gives 13, and for "1010" it gives 5. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Aside: `'0'` is both much more portable and much more relevant than `48`

Comment: @Caleth could you explain more?

Comment: You are dealing with `char` arithmetic, it is much more natural to use `char` literals. There are text encodings where the digit `'0'` does not have the code that is decimal `48`. E.g. in [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) it is `240`

Comment: You're working the digits backwards.

Comment: @Caleth Ok, understand, but it still doesn't fix my problem.

Comment: Something as simple as printing out the value of `W` inside the loop would be an easy debugging technique that could inform you of what's happening.  You could also work through the problem on paper and compare that to what your code is doing.

Comment: @Qbek12321 indeed, which is why I labelled it an aside

Comment: Thanks everyone, I fixed it

Comment: As another aside, this program will have undefined behavior for strings of length 0 or 1.

Comment: @paddy and (before C++20), undefined for long strings

Comment: As yet another aside, "decimal" is a format for writing a textual representation of a number. You're converting a binary representation of an integer to the corresponding integer, not to "decimal".

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating in the wrong direction, and you are potentially reading off the end of the string.

```
#include <string>
#include <climits>

int bintodec(std::string s)
{
    if (s.size() > (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT)) throw std::runtime_error("input too long");

    int W = 0;
    for(char c : s)
    {
        W *= 2;
        W += (c - '0');
    }
    return W;
}
```